# How to require inside style

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to require an image from a location inside the SRC folder in React (not from public unfortunately) and the specific name of that image will be granted from props.

The issue is that I need the image to be set as the background image of a `<div />`. The image doesn't show up.

I tried that:

```
<div
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url('${require(`../../assets/images/home/${banner?.srcString}`)}')`,
        backgroundSize: "cover"
      }}
    />
```

Is there any way to solve this without using `<img />` and without moving all images to `/public`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not require images dynamically from `src` directory, and it's not just limited to React, it's about all JavaScript frameworks that use Webpack internally. Also, this is exactly one of the use cases of `public` directory, as it's been mentioned in the documentation: [When to Use the public Folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/#when-to-use-the-public-folder)

You can also check the following links for more discussions around this question:

[Load local images in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154939/load-local-images-in-react-js/44158919#44158919)

[How to give Image src dynamically in react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033765/how-to-give-image-src-dynamically-in-react-js)

[React, load images local from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58553309/react-load-images-local-from-json)