# Image doesn't show up with props in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a local image and I want to put on my webpage with **Props**. I did `src={require('../images/my-image.png')}` but it didn't work.
It only works with importing the image file, But I want it to be dynamic.

The resulting img element is this:
[image]

App.js:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <Cards img="my-image.png" />
      </div>
  )
}
```

Cards.js:

```
export default function Card(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={`../images/${props.img}`} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Totally, I can not put image file in `src` attribute in JSX, even something like this:
`<img src="../images/my-image.png" />`

Comment: How specifically does this fail?  In the rendered HTML in your browser, what is the resulting `<img>` element?  What is the `src` attribute of that element?  Does the browser make a request for that image URL?  What is the server's response?

Comment: Import images in App.js and pass it as props to Cards.js

Comment: @David i'm pretty sure the location of the file tha I gave it to src is right. for the resulting of img element, check the post again, I edited it

Comment: @AbinThaha But, the number of photos is large

Comment: @saleh: Being "pretty sure" is a good start, but actually debugging and observing will be much more useful.  Use your browser's debugging tools to observe the actual results.  What is the exact HTML for that `<img>`?  In the network tab of the debugging tools, is a request made for the image file?  What is the server's response?  Don't assume, debug and observe.

Comment: @David I checked it in Dev Tools. the `src` of img element is the same with what my image location is

Comment: You should move your assets to the public folder instead of keeping them in the src folder. Also, you can use CDN for images if available. Please refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58553309/react-load-images-local-from-json . My Working Code Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-borg-usgyqv

Comment: @shalinimandal I did it but it gives me this error: `Module not found: You attempted to import ../../public/images/airbnb-logo.png which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.`

Comment: Please check out codesanbox link in my comment. You dont need to import the image. Use it like this: <img width="100" src={`/images/${props.img}`} alt="sample" />

Comment: @saleh, a functional approach to import all (using `importAll`) the images can be done

Comment: @shalinimandal  thank you so much it worked!! if you want, post it as the answer to accept your answer.

Comment: @saleh: And what is the server's response for the request of that image?  You keep insisting that everything is correct instead of observing the actual results.  Your code [demonstrably works](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-swirles-0d34dt?file=/src/App.js) as-is, provided that the image is actually available where you assume it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move your assets to the public folder instead of keeping them in the src folder. Also, you can use CDN for images if available.

Please refer to this link: [React, load images local from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58553309/react-load-images-local-from-json)

My Working Code Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-borg-usgyqv

Answer (score 0):

hello if you want to make the image url dynamic you can write it like this :

```
<img src={require(`../images/${image}`)} alt="product" />
```

reference : [Load images based on dynamic path in ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334874/load-images-based-on-dynamic-path-in-reactjs)

Comment: It doesn't work :[   In Dev Tools the `src` of img element became to [object Module]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the `importAll` work for you? Check the below link and confirm if this work for you.

[Dynamically import images from a directory using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118296/dynamically-import-images-from-a-directory-using-webpack)

At the end of importAll, you will have an array of all the images, and based on your requirement, you can pass the specified image as prop to Cards.js

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple if you have a 'png' all you have to do is import the 'png'
then pass it as a prop. Your mistake is trying to use a relative path:

This is not correct
<img src={`../images/${props.img}`} />

This is the correct way : `<img src={props.img}/>`

If you want to load an SVG the best way is to convert it into a React component like this.

import React from 'react'

export default function MySVG() {

```
   return (
    <svg className="leftArrowSvg" width="6px" height="10px" viewBox="0 0 6 10" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="Version-1" stroke="none" strokeWidth="1" fill="none" fillRule="evenodd" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
            <g id="Replay-Meeting---Key-Word-Tag" transform="translate(-37.000000, -40.000000)" stroke="#ffffff" strokeWidth="2">
                <g id="Header" transform="translate(0.000000, 24.000000)">
                    <g id="Back-Button" transform="translate(38.000000, 8.000000)">
                        <polyline id="Arrow" transform="translate(2.000000, 13.000000) rotate(-360.000000) translate(-2.000000, -13.000000) " points="4 9 0 13 4 17"> </polyline>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
)
```

}